# Manipulate video frame before saving

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, video-capture

I'm currently developing an application for Windows Phone 8 which capture video from camera and save to phone.
Now I'm able to capture the video but I want to access the video frame and do some manipulating before  saving it.
I've look at both `CaptureSource` and `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` but found no event to get the frame before it's saved.

Anyone has an idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

check **PreviewFrameAvailable** event of **AudioVideoCaptureDevice**.I am using same event and able to get frame from video.